# Change document in Sharepoint Document Library during workflow to read only or editable only for user

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, power-automate, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I'm currently building a document control/approval system within a Sharepoint Document Library that interacts with a Power Automate workflow by pressing a button in a column. One of the requirements is that the client would want the document to be only editable by certain users during the flow. I have sketched out this scenario:

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sruz0.png)

The reviewer and approver are set in columns by the creator before the document is sent by pressing a button in a column. This starts the workflow:

[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf2Nz.png)

The flow works as intended but I haven't implemented the requirement about the edit permissions yet as I'm a bit stuck on the implementation.

I looked at the following during my own research:

- Sharepoint check in and out functionality: this does not seem to be tied to certain users such as the reviewer/approver email
- Sharepoint HTTP request to make the document read only: this seems to make the whole document just read only

I noticed that the Word editor itself has the following properties:

[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mueMS.png)

Is it possible to change this state of the document during the workflow?

Would love to hear your suggestions!

Comment: can you please explain why the SharePoint REST API (or HTTP request as you put) is not suitable for you? Me and my colleagues moslty accomplish this by setting a default permission setting for the document library, and at certain milestones break permission inheritance/grant access to person or group/revoke access/re-establish inheritance.